# switching beamer mode with commands

Tags: beamer

I have a beamer main document which is called by various wrappers and I want to make all `\mode`-switching dependent from commands defined in the preamble of this wrappers. For normal modes like `\mode<presentation>` this works fine, but the only way I found to include `\mode*` in this system was to hack an internal command.

Has someone a better idea to achieve the same goal? And do someone some danger in my redefinition (apart from the general danger to redefine internal commands)?

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\newcommand\secondmode{presentation}
\newcommand\mainmode{*}
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@@@mode<#1>{\if#1*
                          \expandafter\@firstoftwo
                        \else
                          \expandafter\@secondoftwo
                        \fi
                        {\beamer@modeoutsideframe}
                        {\beamer@closer\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\beamer@modeinline<#1>}{\beamer@switchmode<#1>}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mode
<\mainmode>
some text outside a frame in main mode
\begin{frame}
test in frame in main mode
\end{frame}


\mode
<\secondmode>

some text outside a frame in second mode

\begin{frame}
second mode in a frame
\end{frame}

\mode
<\mainmode>

some text outside a frame


\mode
<all>
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know beamer well enough to be able to say whether a completely different technique should be used but at least I think you want to change

```
\if#1*


\if*#1%
```

as otherwise if the first two letters of the mode name are the same it will expand to true and typeset the remaining letters followed by a `*`.

In the MWE it is testing the `p` and `r` of `presentation` so it happens to take the right branch, but compare with:

```
\newcommand\secondmode{ppesentation}
```

Comment: Good point. It doesn't matter currently but is naturally cleaner.